# Multilingual Site - Redirection

Tags: php, multilingual

I am trying to implement a language based redirection. Our site has sub-domains for different languages ie es.domain.com // de.domain.com etc. What i am trying to do is include the following code on all pages

```
<?php   

    $lng = array( 'en'=>'www', 'de'=>'de'); // more languages
    $defaultLang = 'en'; // Index of the default (and fallback) language
    $cookieName = "_dmLang"; // Set up the cookie name

    $lang = trim(substr($_GET['lang'], 0, 2));

    if (empty($lang)) $lang = trim($_COOKIE[$cookieName]);

    if (empty($lang)) $lang = trim(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2));

    if (empty($lang) || empty($lng[$lang])) $lang = $defaultLang;

    setcookie($cookieName, $lang, time()+3600*24*30);
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://".$lng[$lang].".domain.com" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

?>
```

The language will change when you call /?lang=de

Are there any server/load implications when using this code? Is there a better way to implement this?